# Query takes too long to execute when i add where clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an 4 tables join query, when i execute without "where" takes like 13 seconds with where takes like 8 minutes.

I have no idea what to do in my mind when u use where to filter improve query perfomance but i'm mistaken

```
SELECT distinct  tb_ProdutoComercial.nm_prodcomerc as tx_nome,
         tb_parceiro.id_prodcomerc_pr as id_produto
        FROM  tb_vendedor
       left join  tb_tokenidparc
       on  tb_vendedor.nu_cdVendedorS4E =  tb_tokenidparc.nu_cdVendedor4E_tk 
       left join  tb_parceiro
       on  tb_tokenidparc.nu_cdCorretoraS4E_tk =  tb_parceiro.id_corretora_pr
       left join  tb_ProdutoComercial
       on  tb_ProdutoComercial.id_prodcomerc =  tb_parceiro.id_prodcomerc_pr
      where tb_ProdutoComercial.en_status = '1'
```

[EXPLAIN With Where](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTd2C.png)
[EXPLAIN Without Where](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clFtI.png)

I'm looking for something with the same perfomance without where

Comment: Give us the `EXPLAIN` output of the two queries.

Comment: The queries are the same but without where in the last row take less time, the query works fine but the problem is the time as i wrote on the **TOP** of the question

Comment: "The queries are the same, except for the difference." Yes, I know the issue is it being slow. Giving us the `EXPLAIN` output for both queries will help people advise you as to a solution. `EXPLAIN` tells us what decisions MySQL is making when it executes your query.

Comment: I added in the description.

Comment: Do you have an index on tb_ProdutoComercial.en_status? My guess is you don't and adding one will improve things by much. Difficult to say though.

Comment: Your `WHERE` clause turns your `LEFT JOIN` into `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: as @eric said your negating your left joins with the `where` clause.  This occurs because the join keeps the vendor, and related tokenIDparcs and related parceiro's and related produtocomercial... but then eliminates all records where ProdutoComercial en_status is not equal to 1.  Thus all NULLS created by the left joins are lost.  To correct this  change your "WHERE" to "AND" to see if that resolves your issue.  This adds time becuse the filter has to be built on ALL the records * records in the joins and not just on ProdutoComercial.

Comment: I find another field to filter the table in the tb_vendedor and now the query works fine with `WHERE`.

Comment: @xQbert i've tried to add `AND` instead of `WHERE` but i get null output in some rows

Comment: @MarcoFalcao that's to be expected given the left joins.  So do you really want left joins or do you want inner?  Are you after ONLy those records which exist in ALL the tables or show all tb_vendedor and the related records in the related tables?  IF you want only those records in ALL The tables you don't want to use left joins as that will increase the record volume which you then eliminate using the where clause.  Better off to make the joins INNER Joins for performance and reduce the record volume

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this run better?

```
   SELECT distinct  tb_ProdutoComercial.nm_prodcomerc as tx_nome
        ,tb_parceiro.id_prodcomerc_pr as id_produto
    FROM  tb_vendedor
        left join  tb_tokenidparc on  tb_vendedor.nu_cdVendedorS4E =  tb_tokenidparc.nu_cdVendedor4E_tk 
        left join  tb_parceiro on tb_tokenidparc.nu_cdCorretoraS4E_tk =  tb_parceiro.id_corretora_pr
        left join  (select * from tb_ProdutoComercial where en_status='1')  tb_ProdutoComercial on tb_ProdutoComercial.id_prodcomerc =  tb_parceiro.id_prodcomerc_pr
```

Comment: The same performance but also thank's for trying to help i'm already solve with other table where.

Comment: This can be useful in like 90% of the cases. Nobody added more answers so i think yours can be the best one.

Answer (score 1):

As you are joining the tables on left side but you also filter them too that is the reason it is taking much time.
Here actually 5 queries are running according to the query.